# Calling getBoundingClientRect() on an element just after appending it to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, getboundingclientrect

Calling getBoundingClientRect() on an element just after appending it to the DOM returns incorrect values.

I guess the rendering engine doesn't have enough time to layout the element

CSS

```
.test {
    width:100px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:black;
}

.test--portrait {
    background-color:black;
    width:10px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Javascript

```
let portrait = true;
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('class', portrait ? 'test--portrait' : 'test');

document.body.appendChild(div);

console.dir(div.getBoundingClientRect());
```

The problem gets solved when calling getBoundingClientRect() with a fresh stack

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.dir(div.getBoundingClientRect());
});
```

Is there any other, more elegant, way to get box's measurements just after appending it, without having to call setTimeout function?

Comment: "I guess the rendering engine doesn't have enough time to layout the element" the rendering engine is not involved here, the box calculation should happen when you call `getBoundingClientRect()`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for responding. The code is within the question.

Comment: But this code only doesn't **reproduce** the error you describe: https://jsfiddle.net/fnmwet3y/ The returned DOMRect has its width set to 10 and its height set to 100, as expected. SO you certainly have something more that you don't show us.